# .NET Entity Framework and stored procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to EF and I got a bit of a philosophical question: all the books, videos, online courses etc - go on and on about working directly with table databases - i.e. with classes that correspond directly to them. How the class I create will abstract away the tables and all that. and then the entire books or courses show all the things I can do to a class that will in turn happen at the database table - the CRUD operations and such.

And I'm thinking - we never work directly with tables, and there are reasons for it. Its such a bad idea - be for us to do it manually or for a framework to handle it for us. We always work with stored procedures, which is the way it should be done (they return SELECTs which JOINs from a bunch of tables typically, and this way we exploit the relational model and encapsulate it. we give permissions to execute stored procedures, not directly, full access to tables, etc etc...)

But all the EF material is 99% on OR mapping which is code-to-physical table, and then a quick mention that its possible to do it with stored procedures.

So... is that the thinking behind the EF philosophy? did I get it right and... what were MS people thinking??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is really ORM vs non-ORM. You mention stored procedures being the "correct" way to do it and I think most people ten years ago would've agreed with you. However, ORM's, like you said, are merely a more expressive, human-readable abstraction on top of SQL (or any query language).

There's something to be said about over-permissioning and ORM's definitely do require more permissions on a database than just `execute` on stored procedures. The trade-off in security (if it truly can't be controlled at another level) is developer speed, testability, and maintainability. That's not to say that query languages aren't able to be any of those things but that's a main goal of abstractions.

I've worked at shops that have been on both sides of the coin. In *my* experience, the shops who use ORM's also seem to have higher velocity. Whether directly correlated, I cannot say.

Comment: Now this is very interesting. of course there's nothing wrong with another abstraction on top of SQL. but the abstraction can be based on stored procs and the data they bring back , not directly on tables - and while EF can do both, every book or online class is 95% on direct work with tables. Now what realy interests me is that you said '10 years ago...' I havent been out on the market for 12 years now, and what I'd really like to know: has the market in general shifted away from stored procs and into work directly with tables?

Comment: For enterprise level projects in some spots, raw SQL/stored procs is still 100% necessary for performance. However, especially for smaller products, ORM's are leaps and bounds faster than stored procedures on both the development and maintenance side of the equation. This site itself uses an ORM, Dapper, which I'd classify as a ORM-lite - abstracting out just the **super** high-level stuff out of the box. This is, of course, all my opinion and my ancedotal evidence but I think a developer today would have better luck job finding, being successful, etc. if they were familiar with ORMs.

Answer (score 1):

There is more: EF is not bound or limited to SQL Server. It's an abstraction of the datalayer which has some benefits over the database approach.

Btw, you can call stored procedures in EF, but still, here some other benefits:

- abstracting data access
- having data tables, views etc well defined in code. This helps prevent mapping mistakes.
- code first has very well defined migration strategies
- and; it allows you to switch your actual database type. This is helpful when writing tests.
- finally: it can save a lot of time and has not a really steep learning curve for people that know C#

Answer (score 0):

Please first of all note that you can also have classes representing Views, and also you can execute stored procedures using EF.

And also when you do joins or use navigational properties like category.Products, note that the same joins are being created by EF and executed.

So EF is just a way to make it easier to work with database, but it is not replacing the functionalities we had. I you want something to work with stored procedures do it. This is an example from my real code that uses stored procedure:

```
List<Flower> flowers =  = context.Flowers.FromSqlRaw("GetFlowers {0}, {1}, {2}", domain, country, currency).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I understand you can execute stored procs. I am just surprised at their total focus on working directly with tables...

Comment: for small projects (that are very big percentage) working directly with tables is ok